# Angular Form nesting and conditional field issues

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-forms, angular2-formbuilder

I am wanting to create an angular form dynamically from json. 
This form has a variety of field types (input, date, number, select)
These field types can also be secondary conditional fields based on select values. (See formData.js)

The form needs root level objects in the FormGroup in angular, but also needs FormArrays for fields that the user can add more of (multiSelect:true in the data).

I have it working to render the top level fields, and the mutliselect fields. 
The issue is when I am trying to render the conditional fields and have it work in a structure of angular Forms values collection.

I have put together a stackblitz of the form element of my application. 
The form is built in a loop from the formData, with a dynamic Field Directive using factoryResolver to create the components.

**The error I specifically get is `control.registerOnChange is not a function`. The angular form Object has all the fields where they are needed in this iteration including multiselect fields.**

But the conditionals don't currently render.

Any help on this would be appreciated, and if any more information is needed let me know.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bxznoc

Comment: I changed the multiSelect conditional rendering to include a [formGroup]="dyanmicField" this seems to have solved my issue. But I have refactored slightly more in the sense, the non multiselect conditional dropdown outputs its conditionals in root of the FormGroup object. They didnt need to be a group in themselves.

Comment: please edit your question rather than adding comments.  Also please provide full code HERE rather than an offsite link (which many will NOT visit for many valid reasons)

Comment: Way too much code to paste into here. I figured it out though thanks.